# Как извлечь иконку из исполняемого файла .exe

Tags: c#

Наткнулся на вот такой вот класс:
[Класс для извлечение иконок](http://alexeyworld.com/blog/extract_icon_class.42.aspx)

У меня путь до иконки выходит в текстбокс, как извлечь иконку?)

Comment: Из ресурсов дергайте каким-нибудь редактором ресурсов.

Comment: Не из ресурсов) Если бы мне нужно было из ресурсов я бы сказал)).. Левые проги не нужны чисто средством c#!

Comment: тогда LockResource и все что надо для него используйте, он вернут указатель на нужный ресурс.

Comment: "Не из ресурсов)" - а где, Вы думаете, находится иконка в exe-файле?

Comment: Крч я понял что толкового точного ответа я тут не добъюсь!

Comment: [тут](http://vec3.ca/extracting-icons-from-pe-files/) можете посмотреть.

Comment: `.exe` от .net или нативного приложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вы можете воспользоваться классом `Icon` из WinForms, который умеет делать то, что вам надо:

```
Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(тут путь к вашему файлу)
```

Например, если вы хотите сохранить иконку в файл, то делайте так:

```
using (var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exepath))
using (var file = File.Create(iconpath))
    icon.Save(file);
```

Или вы можете сконвертировать иконку в битмап при помощи [`ToBitmap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).

Если ваше приложение — не WinForms, подключите сборку `System.Drawing`.

Comment: Да мне нужно просто нужно вытащить из .exe файла иконку в формате .ico ( хорошего качества ) а тут я полагаю только 16х16 дают).

Comment: string rout = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string rout2 = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

Icon ico = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(rout);
Stream save = File.Create(rout2);
ico.Save(save);
save.Close(); Но качество ужасное у иконки, как сделать сохранить норм иконку?

Comment: Подыму тему), а вытащить более оригинальную иконку в хорошем качестве возможно?

Comment: @ArteS: Ну, можно [попробовать P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.extracticonex), вы вытащите все ресурсы. Но где там именно большая иконка, я навскидку не скажу.

Comment: Да мне бы собственно не самую большую, а самую качественную примером глубиной цвета в 32х32.

Comment: Вроде нашёл что-то но не могу сообразить как сохранить иконку, `Icon icon1 = IconFactory (textbox, 32, 32);` взял из: https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/234043-how-extract-specific-icon-ico-file

Comment: @ArteS: Ну, если есть иконка, то `using (var file = File.Create(iconpath)) icon1.Save(file);`